# SQL Update list at once

Tags: sql

What is the easiest way to update column2 into (1,2,3,4,5) using an update statement?

column1 = A, B, C , D , E
column2 = 5, 1, 3, 2, 4

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TableName SET Column2 = CASE WHEN Column1 = 'A' THEN 5
                                    WHEN Column2 = 'B' THEN 1
                                    WHEN Column2 = 'C' THEN 3 
                                    .........
                               END
```